# Prove spectral norm $\|A\|\geq x^T A x$, $\forall x$ where $\|x\|_2=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-norm

I'm not sure if this is true, as it is something I am inferring from a proof that I am trying to understand.

I know that $\|A\|=\max\{-\lambda_{\min}(A),\lambda_\max(A)\}$ for $A$ symmetric. However I don't know how to prove the statement in the title.

Comment: Actually, $\|A\|$ is the maximum singular value of $A$. Is that the definition of the spectral norm that you prefer?

Comment: @TheoBendit Ah sorry, I was thinking about when $A$ is symmetric

Comment: Even if $A$ is symmetric, you're looking at the maximum *absolute value* of the eigenvalues. :-)

Comment: @TheoBendit Right again. Maybe I should ban myself from using StackExchange while sleep-deprived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is symmetric it’s diagonalizable and has an orthonormal basis $v_i$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$.

Then write $x=\sum_i (x,v_i)v_i$, so that:

$$|x^TAx|=|\sum_{i=1} (x,v_i)^2\lambda_i|\leq |\lambda_M| \|x\|^2,$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: I've never heard of a "north honor map basis." I've been able to show that $x^TAx=\sum_i (x^Tv_i)^2 \lambda_i\leq \sum_i (x^Tv_i)^2 \max\{ -\lambda_\min,\lambda_\max\}=  \max\{ -\lambda_\min,\lambda_\max\} x^T \sum_i v_i v_i^T x$. Clearly I am done if $\sum_i v_i v_i^T$ is the identity matrix. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @Dan: haha, iOS autocorrect: "orthonormal." In response to your question, first make sure to have absolute value signs, as even the largest eigenvalue can be negative.  Your last equality is not correct as written. Instead, I'm using Cauchy Schwarz: $(x,v_i)\leq \|x\|\|v_i\|$, in addition to the orthonormality of $v_i$.

Comment: I don't see how the last equality is incorrect. I was just using that $\sum_i (x^T v_i)^2 = \sum_i x^T v_i v_i^T x = x^T \sum_i v_i v_i^T x$

Comment: Oh I didn’t see the $x$ outside your sum.

Answer (score 0):

Because $A$ is symmetric, there exists an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. You should decompose $x$ in such a basis to prove the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a separate answer so the solution is complete.

Let $A=\sum_i\lambda_iv_iv_i^T$, where $\{v_i\}_i$ is an orthonormal eigenbasis of $A$, as $A$ is symmetric. Then,

$$x^TAx=x^TA\sum_i v_i v_i^Tx = x^T\sum_i \lambda_iv_i v_i^T x \leq x^T \max_i\{\lambda_i\}x=\max_i\{\lambda_i\}=\|A\|.$$